# Shopify - How to complete abandoned checkout using Graphql

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-app

I have created abandoned checkout using "checkoutcreate" mutation of the Shopify storefront API. It is successfully created, but how do I mark it as completed using Rest API or Graphql API, I have tried the "checkoutCompleteFree" mutation, but it throws a "Payment Pending" error.

I have tried to mark it from Shopify admin too, but it is not possible from there too, they just give the option to archive.

Comment: Have you tried completing the checkout by actually completing the order and thus satisfying the payments etc? Seems logicial right?

Comment: That will work, but I have to complete the abandoned cart checkout via Rest API or graphql API.

Comment: It's an odd use case. You probably want to create a draft order from the abandoned cart, and then send the customer a link to make a payment.